# Why do x+0 and x|0 have different results?

Tags: c++, c

Why do x+0 and x|0 have different results?

Below is my code.

My environment is WSL (Debian Sid) + GCC 10.2.1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

/**
 * Do rotating left shift. Assume 0 <= n < w
 * Examples when x = 0x12345678 and w = 32:
 * n = 4 -> 0x23456781, n = 20 -> 0x67812345
 */
unsigned rotate_left(const unsigned x, const int n)
{
    const int w = sizeof(unsigned) << 3;
    return (x << n) + (x >> (w - n));
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0x12345678;
    printf("n = 4, %#x -> %#x\n", x, rotate_left(x, 4));
    printf("n = 20, %#x -> %#x\n", x, rotate_left(x, 20));
    printf("n = 0, %#x -> %#x\n", x, rotate_left(x, 0));
}
```

when n = 0, the result is 0x2468acf0.

when i replace `return (x << n) + (x >> (w - n))` with `return (x << n) | (x >> (w - n))`, i get 0x12345678.

Comment: What led you to believe that `(x >> (w - n))` is 0, because that would be the only case where both alternatives would be equivalent? Just because `n` is 0 doesn't mean that the entire expression is 0.

Comment: I use gdb to view this result is 0

Comment: @rici 'the OP is probably not the only person who doesn't know that you can't do x>>32 if x is an int' undoubtably true.  Only professional/enthusiast programmers would be expected to know that variables have limits.

Comment: @martin: I've certainly worked with professional programmers who weren't aware that `x>>32` is undefined behaviour. Many people (who possibly should know better but evidently don't) seem to think that the result will be 0 if `x` is a 32-bit type. (Indeed, there's a certain logic to that belief. It just happens not to be true.)

Comment: @BralowQin *"I use gdb to view this result is 0"* -- viewing values through a debugger is usually good, but expressions are sometimes finicky. If you want to keep the assumption that the result is 0, you should simplify your test case by using `0` instead of `(x >> (w - n))`. This will not give your desired functionality, but it would demonstrate your issue *if your assumption is accurate*. If/when this fails to demonstrate your issue, output `(x >> (w - n))` to see what your *compiler* believes the expression evaluates to.

Comment: @sam, by the way: if you shift a `w`-bit number left by `n`, then the `w-n` low-order bits are now at the high end, and the `n` low-order bits are 0. Correspondingly, when you shift another copy of the number right by `w-n`, then the `n` high-order bits now occupy the `n` low-order positions and the high-order `w-n` bits are 0. So there is no column in which both of those two shifted results is 1, and it's entirely reasonable to expect that add and bitwise-or will have the same result. And it will work in practice if `0<n<w`. But since C doesn't let you shift by the wordlength, `n==0` fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `x` is an integer type with at most 32 bits, then `x>>32` is **Undefined Behaviour**, which means that the result can be absolutely anything (and it can be a different anything in different programs). (Also true of `x<<32`.) [Note 1]

From §6.5.7 para 3 of the C standard, concerning `<<` and `>>` operators, emphasis added:

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than **or equal to** the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

As a result, your rotate function won't work if `n <= 0` or `n >= w`, and you should test for those cases rather than assume they won't occur (since they obviously will).

---

#### Notes

1. In practice, on Intel hardware (and probably others), a shift by the width of the operand is a no-op, not "clear to 0". So `x>>32` is `x`, as is `x<<0`, and thus the sum is twice `x`, while the bitwise or is exactly `x`. But you cannot rely on that fact, because it's **Undefined Behaviour**, and compiler optimizations might result in other arbitrary results.

Comment: Why would `sizeof(unsigned)` be 32? A 32-byte `unsigned` is I suppose _possible_, but seems unlikely.

Comment: @nathan; `sizeof(unsigned)` is probably 4, in which case `sizeof(unsigned)<<3`, which is **what the code actually says**, is 32.

Comment: Oh! Yes, somehow just completely missed that `w` wasn't just `sizeof(unsigned)`. Thanks

Comment: Note: if you want to be able to rely on the Intel behavior, simply specify `shift % 32u` in place of `shift`; the compiler will optimize it down to the single instruction (whereas branching might generate bad code). Note that the shift *must* be unsigned. It may be useful to `#define bitsizeof(x) (sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT)`

Comment: @rici I specifically mentioned that "it must be unsigned" in the sense of "to trigger this optimization". The reason is that signed modulo can return a negative result (I guess I could've written it as `& mask` in the first place).

Comment: @o11c: Sorry, I misunderstood. C's `%` operator is also a pain. Yes, `n & (w - 1)` would work.